# Set new field in azure search to default value

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure search and when I *add* a new field it becomes null.
Is there a way to have a default value?

```
PUT {{servicename}}/indexes/{{indexname}}?api-version=2019-05-06
Content-Type: application/json   
api-key: {{adminkey}}

{  
  "fields": [
    {  
      "name": "rid",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": true
    },   
    {
      "name": "NewField",
      "type": "Edm.Boolean"
    }
}
```

and search result is

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://whatever.search.windows.net/indexes('indexname')/$metadata#docs(*)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 0.55735236,
            "rid": "asdfasdf",
            "Email": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to have a default value?

Based on the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/update-index), no.

[image]

Once a new field is added, you will have to [`update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents) existing documents manually to set a value for that added field. As mentioned in the documentation, you can use `merge` as `@search.action` to only update the newly added fields.